# Threaded RadioButtonList

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

What is the best way to build a dynamic *Threaded* ASP.net radio button list?  I am not that familiar with `RadioButtonLists` and it is my understanding that ASP.net doesn't like the application of individual styling of `ListItems`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, why not use the `RadioButtonList` control, with a `ReapeatDirection="Horizontal"`?

Comment: Sorry SO displayed something different than intended.  I meant to display a hierarchy of radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Threaded like hierarchical and in a tabbed format?  You are going to have to build a custom control if you are looking for this kind of functionality; it isn't available really easily out of the box.  The list controls aren't the greatest for extending out of the box unfortunately.